# How to use UIPagingView with multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to create an app, like the home screen, where you can scroll between pages. All the examples given are just multiple pages that add numbers. Is there a way to make each one in a separate view controllers or separate UIViews?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with UIScrollView with paging enabled. 
[UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

A complete tutorial: [Paging UIScrollView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)